# Showing events in a md-dialog from the clicked date on a calendar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dialog, angular-material, mean-stack

I am developping a MEAN stack application, and I got a question about using md-dialog from Angular Material.

On my webpage I have a calendar displayed with the events displayed on the calendar. When the user clicks on that date, I want a dialog popping up with a list and some info about the events taking place that day.

I have succesfully implemented the dialog behaviour of showing up when clicked on a date. Now my problem is that the data in the dialog isn't updated.

This is the function in my controller that's called when a date is clicked in the calendar

```
function dayClick(date){
      vm.dateClicked = date;
      getEventsByDay(date);
      showDialog();
    }
```

As you can see I then call another method in my controller to get the events taking place on the selected date from my database.

```
function getEventsByDay(date){
      vm.eventsday = eventService.getEventsByDay(date).then(function(res){
        vm.eventsday = res;
        return vm.eventsday;
      });
    }
```

The events are successfully retreived from the database.
After we get the events are retreived, showDialog is called.

```
function showDialog(ev) {
      $mdDialog.show({
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        controller: MainController,
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        templateUrl: '/templates/dialogevent.html',
        hasBackdrop: true,
        panelClass: 'dialog-events',
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
        escapeToClose: true
      });
    }
```

So when using some logging in my code I found out that somehow the dialog is rendered and called before data is retreived. I tried to chain the methods to force them to execute after one another, but I can't seem to get that to work.

Any suggestions ?

**Edit:** 
This is the template html

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Event Dialog">
<md-toolbar>
  <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
    <h2>Events on {{ctrl.dateClicked | date:"dd/MM/yyyy"}}</h2>
    <span flex></span>
    <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="cancel()">
      <md-icon aria-label="Close dialog">close</md-icon>
    </md-button>
  </div>
</md-toolbar>
<md-dialog-content style="max-width:800px;max-height:810px; ">
  <md-list>
    <md-list-item ng-repeat="event in ctrl.eventsday">
      <div class="md-list-item-text">
        <h4>{{event.name}}</h4>
        <h5>{{event.eventType.name}}</h5>
        <p>{{event.description}}</p>
      </div>
    </md-list-item>
  </md-list>
</md-dialog-content>
```

**Edit 2:**
I'm initializing "vm.clickedDate" in the top of my controller

```
vm.dateClicked = new Date();
```

New date will give today's date. When I add events with today's date, the events are **not** shown in the dialog.

**Edit 3:**
This is the complete controller code

```
(function() {

'use strict';

angular.module('ptlab').controller('MainController', MainController);

MainController.$inject = ['$http', '$log', 'auth', '$state', '$stateParams', 'eventService', 'MaterialCalendarData', '$scope', '$mdDialog', '$timeout'];

function MainController($http, $log, auth, $state, $stateParams, eventService, MaterialCalendarData, $scope, $mdDialog, $timeout) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.users = [];
    vm.getUsers = getUsers;
    vm.openingsuren = [];
    vm.events = [];
    vm.setDayContent = setDayContent;
    vm.dateClicked = new Date();
    $scope.dayClick = dayClick;
    $scope.cancel = cancel;
    vm.showDialog = showDialog;
    vm.eventsday = {};
    vm.getEventsByDay = getEventsByDay;
    vm.userStudent = true;
    vm.userCoworker = true;
    vm.userManager = true;

    activate();


    function activate() {
      return load();
    }
    function load(){
        getUsers();
        getOpeningsuren();
        getEvents();

    }

    function getUsers() {
        return auth.getAll()
            .then(function(data) {
                vm.users = data.data;
                return vm.users;
            });
    }

    function getOpeningsuren(){
        return $http.get('/javascripts/content.json').success(function(data){
          vm.openingsuren = data.openingsuren.dag;
        });
    }

    function getEvents(){
      vm.events = eventService.getAll().then(function(res){
        vm.events = res.data;
        var evenement;
        for(evenement of vm.events){
          var content = createContentCalendar(evenement);
          setDayContent(evenement.startdate, content);
        }
        return vm.events;
      });
    }

    function setDayContent(date, content){
      MaterialCalendarData.setDayContent(new Date(date), content);
    }

    function dayClick(date){
      vm.dateClicked = date;
      getEventsByDay(date);

    }

    function cancel(){
      $mdDialog.cancel();
    }

    function createContentCalendar(evenement){
      var string = "";
      string += "<div class='item-box text-center'><h7>" + evenement.name + "</h7></div>";
      return string;
    }

    function showDialog(ev) {
      console.log("showDialog");
      console.log(vm.eventsday);
      $mdDialog.show({
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        controller: MainController,
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        templateUrl: '/templates/dialogevent.html',
        hasBackdrop: true,
        panelClass: 'dialog-events',
        targetEvent: ev,
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
        escapeToClose: true,
        allowParentalScroll: true
      });
    }

    function getEventsByDay(date){
      vm.eventsday = eventService.getEventsByDay(date).then(function(res){
        vm.eventsday = res;
        $timeout(showDialog, 1000);
        return vm.eventsday;
      });
    }
} })();
```

**Edit4:**
Tried like suggested by adding the following to showDialog:

```
locals: {
    eventsday: vm.eventsday,
    day: vm.dateClicked
},
controller: CalendarController,
controllerAs: 'ctrl'
```

I also made a controller called "CalendarController":

```
(function() {

'use strict';

angular.module('ptlab').controller('CalendarController', CalendarController);

CalendarController.$inject = ['$mdDialog', 'eventsday', 'day'];

function CalendarController($log, auth, $state, $stateParams, $mdDialog, eventsday, day) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.eventsday = eventsday;
    vm.dateClicked = day;


    function cancel(){
      $mdDialog.cancel();
    }
}})();
```

Now I get the error that "CalendarController" used in showDialog is not defined. I've added the calendarcontroller file to my script tags, so it should find the file in my index.ejs. Am I missing something or do I need to inject something else ?

**Edit 5:**
Found the solution. Everything works like in "Edit 4", just forgot the quotes around CalendarController in the show method.

Comment: When I have same problem I wrapped function in $timeout and that's helped. Try $timeout(showDialog) in dayClick(). Be sure your controller has $timeout

Comment: Didn't work. showDialog is still called before the events are fetched.

Comment: increase delay in timeout OR move calling showDialog() at the end of "eventService.getEventsByDay(date).then".  Second is better.

Comment: I moved the showDialog() to then, but the problem is that my "vm.eventsday" in "getEventsByDay" isn't set before showDialog is called. Increasing timeout doesn't work either.

Comment: function getEventsByDay(date){
      vm.eventsday = eventService.getEventsByDay(date).then(function(res){
        vm.eventsday = res;
        $timeout(showDialog);
        return vm.eventsday;
      });
    }


Right?

Comment: Right. Timeout doesn't seem to work. Even when I add a delay of 10 seconds, the dialog instantly pops up when clicked.

Comment: I was using "$timeout(showDialog(), 5000);". When I use "$timeout(showDialog, 5000);", it waits 5 seconds before popping up, but it still doesn't show the data.

Comment: Oh... I skipped you edit. Problem not in order. 

Check *$scope*.eventsday in MainController. Is it exists? I see only  vm.eventsday. "Controller as" vm? 
Where is you JS code? Inside MainController or some other? 
Just check names.

Comment: I edited the post with the complete controller code. $scope.eventsday is undefined. Variable "vm" = this. Naming isn't the problem I think.

Comment: Ok it's all in MainController. Dialog load another isnance of MainController there is this.eventsday is empty. 
You don't need MainController as controller in  $mdDialog.show().

Crearte new controller. And load data in this second Controller OR just set data in second like here https://github.com/angular/material/issues/455#issuecomment-59889129

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to load MainController again in $mdDialog.show. It hasn't data in vm.eventsday during second-time-running.

Just create new controller and inject data there.
So you controller in $mdDialog.show is something like this

```
        locals:{parent: vm},
        controller: function () { this.parent = vm },
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
```

Or see example here https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog it's similar your task

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I edited to post with some new info. I've read the angularjs material api and looked at $mdDialog. Now CalendarController is undefined somehow. It should be recognized.

Comment: Found the solution. Thanks for the help.